# AppleScript : unable to refer to a file

Tags: file, integer, applescript, posix, plist

I have a script with work fine when the file is referred but when I try to add a dialog to select the file I always get an error

```
  set p to "/Users/kevin/Desktop/Time"
set plistfile_path to POSIX file p

set config_file to choose file with prompt "Locate your .plist config file and click OK" of type "plist" default location plistfile_path


tell application "System Events"
    set p_list to property list file (config_file)
    set startTimeValue to value of property list item "startTime" of p_list
end tell
```

Error :

> error "System Events got an error: Can’t make file \"Macintosh
>   HD:Users:kevin:Desktop:Time\" into type integer." number
>   -1700 from file "Macintosh HD:Users:kevin:Desktop:Time" to integer

My original script work with this format :

> set the plistfile_path to "~/Desktop/Time/myTime29_March.plist"

How can I fix the dialog issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An argument of `property list file` cannot be an AppleScript `alias` specifier.

Coerce the alias to text

```
set p_list to property list file (config_file as text)
```